# how to get multiple characters input and do something with it in Python

Tags: python

I need a program that get a 1 line input from user(text) and then give the output as text(I write an example down below)

I tried for **if** but it's only accept one line code and if I write a word that is not defined, it ruin the rest.

```
class meaning():
  def shortcutA (self):
    print ("ice cream")
  def shortcutB (self):
    print ("Choclet cake")

def main():
    m = meaning()

    if input() == "a":
      print("your code is: ")
      m.shortcutA()
    elif input() == "b":
      print("your code is: ")
      m.shortcutB()
    else :
      print ("unrecognized")

print ("Please enter the words :")

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

I expect when I enter **a b** the result be like

```
ice cream 
Choclet cake
```

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print without newline or space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493386/how-to-print-without-newline-or-space)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a for loop to go through the input in a word.

```
class meaning():
  def shortcutA (self):
    print ("ice cream")
  def shortcutB (self):
    print ("Choclet cake")



def main():
    m = meaning()
    print_flag = False
    for i in input():
        if i in ['a', 'b'] and not print_flag:
            print("your code is: ")
            print_flag = True
        if i == "a":
            m.shortcutA()
        elif i == "b":
            m.shortcutB()
        elif i == ' ':
            continue
        else :
             print ("unrecognized")

print ("Please enter the words :")

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

produces:

```
Please enter the words :
your code is: 
ice cream 
Choclet cake
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your `if` input statements.
If you want output according to input separated by spaces, then use this:

```
for x in input():
    if(x=='a'):
         print(m.shortcutA(),end=' ')
    if(x=='b'):
         print(m.shortcutB(),end=' ') 
    else:
         print('unrecognised!')
```

hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a program like this,

```
class meaning():
    def shortcutA(self):
        return "ice cream"

    def shortcutB(self):
        return "Chocolet cake"


def main():
    m = meaning()
    code = ''
    for alphabet in user_input:
        if alphabet == "a":
            code += ' ' + m.shortcutA()
        elif alphabet == "b":
            code += ' ' + m.shortcutB()
    if len(code) == 0:
        print 'Unrecognized.'
    else:
        print 'The code is : ' + code


user_input = raw_input('Please enter the words : \n')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```